# Connecting IBM MQ client with a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-mq

I've an existing rails application that keeps the truck information(driver info, location etc). Now I'm integrating a partner service that send and receive different messages about truck's location, latitude, longitude and speed etc in XML format. Following is the sample data:

```
<VehicleLocation>
  <Vin>vin3</Vin>
  <Timestamp>2015-01-25T17:19:54.000Z</Timestamp>
  <Latitude>39.781662</Latitude>
  <Longitude>-104.943133</Longitude>
  <Altitude>5259</Altitude>
  <Heading>0</Heading>
  <Odometer>20103</Odometer>
  <EngineSpeed>0</EngineSpeed>
  <RoadSpeed>0</RoadSpeed>
  <EngineRunning>false</EngineRunning>
  <Event>SCHED</Event>
</VehicleLocation>
```

While reading the documentation I found that they are using IBM MQ Client as an integration layer for data transfer. IP address will be provided for  the connection. All I've to do is to get messages, parse it and update the truck record in a Sidekiq worker.

In rails what is the best way to connect with their IBM MQ layer using the provided IP and parse the messages? A well-maintained gem or library that is easy to install and manage on production environment as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Googling for this leads to https://github.com/reidmorrison/rubywmq

Comment: There are many gems available like RabbitMQ, MQ Light etc. So, I was confused which one to use

Comment: If you have IBM MQ then you need a Gem that supports IBM MQ.

Comment: I tried the github.com/reidmorrison/rubywmq gem but it doesn't support SSL setup as mentioned here https://github.com/reidmorrison/rubywmq/issues/15

Comment: I couldn't find some other options can you please suggest?

Comment: Well, apparently you are out of luck then. You could help the author of the gem to add SSL support, switch to jruby and use the jruby solution mentioned in the issue you linked.